# Django-CMS throws error on 404 inside apphook

Tags: python, django, placeholder, django-cms

Django-cms throws an error when a 404 occurs inside an apphook:

```
PlaceholderNotFound: "error-code" placeholder not found in an apphook application.
Please use a static placeholder instead.
```

`'error-code'` is a placeholder inside my 404 template.

Is there anything I can do about this?